# Array Multiplication & Sum with JQ?

Tags: arrays, json, math, jq

```
{
  "pricexquant": [
    [
      "20233.54000000",
      "0.00877000"
    ],
    [
      "20233.39000000",
      "0.00999000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

for an array of arrays with 2 elements as strings, how would jq multiply element 1 * element 2 in each array? and from that generate a new array...

eg.

```
{
    [
      "177.4481458"
    ],
    [
      "200.310561"
    ]
}
```

and for that sum the total across all?

Comment: The illustrative output is not valid JSON, and in any case it’s not clear what the final desired output is. If you want a single number, is the intermediate structure really relevant?

Comment: You want the output as decimals or strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
.pricexquant|map(map(tonumber)|.[0] * .[1])|add
```

yields

```
379.5797119
```